# Google Drive API fetch request from browser fails with CORS error when using Google Identity

Tags: javascript, google-api, cors, google-identity

I'm trying to use the Google Identity API to make fetch requests to the Google Drive API from the browser but it fails with the typical CORS error:

`Access to fetch at 'https://googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key=[API_KEY]&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I successfully authorize with the Google Identity API, then make a request with the following function:

```
async function loadFiles(accessToken: string) {
    try {
        const result = await fetch(
            `https://googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key=${encodeURIComponent(data.apiToken)}&access_token=${encodeURIComponent(accessToken as string)}`,
                // `https://googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key=${encodeURIComponent(data.apiToken)}`,
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
                    Accept: 'application/json'
                    // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:5173'
                },
                method: 'GET'
            }
        );
        console.dir(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.dir(error);
    }
}
```

I'm being guided by Google's documentation at https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model#working_with_tokens , but the link to "How to use CORS to access Google APIs" appears to be broken.

I have added `http://localhost:5173` my Authorized JavaScript origins in the Google Console for this project
[image]

This is what the browser sees when making the request:

[image]

Would you have any suggestions on what to try next to fix this? Is this not something that can be done from the client? Or is this something that should be done from the server? I'm trying to avoid doing it on the server because the things I want to accomplish don't really require any work from the server. It seems more efficient to make a request from the client directly to Google rather than client to backend to Google then back to the backend to client.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm the exact same situation as you